# What are the differences between Lwt.async and Lwt_main.run on OCaml/Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, ocaml, js-of-ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I am experimenting with `js_of_ocaml` and node.js. As you know, node.js makes extensive use of callbacks to implement asynchronous requests without introducing explicit threads.

In OCaml we have a very nice threading library, Lwt, coming with a very useful syntax extension. I wrote a prototype with a binding to some node library (a AWS S3 client) and added a lwt-ish layer to hide the callback.

```
open Lwt.Infix
open Printf
open Js

let require_module s =
    Js.Unsafe.fun_call
      (Js.Unsafe.js_expr "require")
      [|Js.Unsafe.inject (Js.string s)|]

let _js_aws = require_module "aws-sdk"

let array_to_list a =
  let ax = ref [] in
  begin
    for i = 0 to a##.length - 1 do
      Optdef.iter (array_get a i) (fun x -> ax := x :: !ax)
    done;
    !ax
  end


class type error = object
end

class type bucket = object
  method _Name : js_string t readonly_prop
  method _CreationDate : date t readonly_prop
end

class type listBucketsData = object
  method _Buckets : (bucket t) js_array t readonly_prop
end

class type s3 = object
  method listBuckets :
    (error -> listBucketsData t -> unit) callback -> unit meth
end

let createClient : unit -> s3 t = fun () ->
  let constr_s3 = _js_aws##.S3 in
  new%js constr_s3 ()


module S3 : sig
  type t
  val create : unit -> t
  val list_buckets : t -> (string * string) list Lwt.t
end = struct
  type t = s3 Js.t

  let create () =
    createClient ()

  let list_buckets client =
    let cell_of_bucket_data data =
      ((to_string data##._Name),
       (to_string data##._CreationDate##toString))
    in
    let mvar = Lwt_mvar.create_empty () in
    let callback error buckets =
      let p () =
        if true then
          Lwt_mvar.put mvar
            (`Ok(List.map cell_of_bucket_data @@ array_to_list buckets##._Buckets))
        else
          Lwt_mvar.put mvar (`Error("Ups"))
      in
      Lwt.async p
    in
    begin
      client##listBuckets (wrap_callback callback);
      Lwt.bind
        (Lwt_mvar.take mvar)
        (function
          | `Ok(whatever) -> Lwt.return whatever
          | `Error(mesg) -> Lwt.fail_with mesg)
    end
end

let () =
  let s3 = S3.create() in
  let dump lst =
    Lwt_list.iter_s
      (fun (name, creation_date) ->
         printf "%32s\t%s\n" name creation_date;
         Lwt.return_unit)
      lst
  in
  let t () =
    S3.list_buckets s3
    >>= dump
  in
  begin
    Lwt.async t
  end
```

Since there is no binding to `Lwt_main` for node.js, I had to run my code with `Lwt.async`. What are the differences between running the code with `Lwt.async` rather than with `Lwt_main.run` – the latter not existing in node.js?  Is it guaranteed that the program will wait until the asynchronous threads are completed before exiting, or is this rather a lucky but random behaviour of my code?

Comment: I've never had to use main run for my nodejs bindings, a top level unit is fine

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Please correct me if I am wrong: the bindings you wrote do not make use of Lwt at all, right? Do you use Lwt in code using these bindings? Maybe you want to add some more details in an answer here, to avoid chatting. :)

Comment: I have stuff to say but its not really an answer, kind of comments and insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Lwt_main.run` function recursively polls the thread whose execution it supervises.  At each iteration, if this thread is still running, the scheduler uses one engine (from `Lwt_engine`) to execute threads waiting for I/Os, either by selecting or synchronising on events.

The natural way to translate this in Node.JS is to use the `process.nextTick` method, which relies on Node.JS own scheduler.  Implementing the `Lwt_main.run` function in this case can be as simple as:

```
let next_tick (callback : unit -> unit) =
  Js.Unsafe.(fun_call
               (js_expr "process.nextTick")
               [| inject (Js.wrap_callback callback) |])

let rec run t =
  Lwt.wakeup_paused ();
  match Lwt.poll t with
    | Some x -> x
    | None -> next_tick (fun () -> run t)
```

This function only run threads of type `unit Lwt.t` but this is the main case for a program.  It is possible to compute arbitrary values using a `Lwt_mvar.t` to communicate.

It is also possible to extend this example to support all sort of hooks, as in the original `Lwt_main.run` implementation.